# How to remove the VS Code Jupyter Notebook deprecation notice?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It is great that I've been informed, but how do I remove the notice? It is just taking up space pointlessly. I tried changing the screen resolution to the highest my monitor allows, but an X was not hiding on the right side.

[image: Deprecation Notice]

Comment: The solution [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7139#issuecomment-903130809) works for me. That switches it to the newer editor.

Comment: Just put `workbench` and `editorAssociations` into search to find the particular option.